# php Content-types

Tags: php, export-to-excel

I'm playing around with exporting dynamic data from a database to the browser.
I see there are different Content-Types, and some I need to ask about.  I must be asking the wrong questions, since I'm not finding detailed information in the search engines.

here's a few I've seen from people's personal scripts.

```
header("Content-type: application/zip;");
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload");
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
```

I can clearly understand "zip", "csv".  But the others leave me with questions. Like, when do i use them?

I've tried x-msdownload for xls files, and it seems to work.  But I see others using vnd.ms-excel.  Why?  Should I be using that?
I've also see octet-stream used for downloading a csv file, generated by php.  Why?

Anyway, I'm not finding much on php.net.  Not to say it's not there, but clear descriptions aren't shown.

Anyone know of a site that breaks down the different content-types, and why they're used?

Comment: well... wikipedia is your friend: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type -> `application/octet-stream` is used to bring a download dialog in front... so you can offer even (for example) a jpeg for download and not opening it directly in browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MIME-Types are not defined by PHP, but they are defined by the IETF in [RFC2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046). Most of them are just for single file types and only useful, if you want to contribute such files. Types starting with `vnd` are vendor specific MIME-Types. Types starting with `x-` are not defined. They mean something like "my custom type", but you should not rely on it. `text/plain` is usually used for not nearer defined ascii content and `application/octet-stream` is nearly the same for binary content.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/ has an exhaustive list of mime types and their associated definition.

Comment: Wow, that truly is "exhaustive."  I'll get my reading glasses and coffee for this.